# Integrate ADO.NET provider on On-premise Data Gateway with PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, exact-online, nmbrs, data-gateway

I am trying to integrate a large number of data sources available through a custom ADO.NET provider on a Windows server into PowerApps. To make the data available, I am using v14 of the On-premise Data Gateway (non-personal mode).

The gateway registers nicely, but for instance in Power BI web I can define a data source based upon a file or website.

But somehow even these file or website connections are not available for display or use in PowerApps.

Documentation is confusing; there seems to be no up-to-date variant yet and some screenshots illustrate it works, some seem to indicate the opposite.

Ultimately I would like to use a local ADO.NET provider with PowerApps to allow access to platforms such as nmbrs, Teamleader or Exact Online.

Is there a recommendation how to get an on-premise file, web-based data or an ADO.NET provider available in PowerApps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks from a willing person within Microsoft, I've learned that as of today the Data Gateway for Power BI and PowerApps does not yet support local ADO.NET providers.